OOM when num_workers>0
I'm trying to implement a simple UNet with different modalities. The issue is training is taking way too long and I'm constantly running into OOM errors when num_workers>0.
def train_batch(self, source, target,extra):
    with profile(activities=[ProfilerActivity.CPU],profile_memory=True, record_shapes=True) as prof:
        source_tensors = [tensor.to(self.device) for tensor in source]
        target_tensors = [tensor.to(self.device) for tensor in target]
        if ("rgb" in self.config["modalities"] or "semantic" in self.config["modalities"]):
            extra_tensors = [tensor.to(device) for tensor in extra]
            category,rgb = extra_tensors
        else:
            category = None
            rgb= None
        source_mag_ir, source_phase_ir, source_mat= source_tensors
        target_mag_ir, target_phase_ir, target_mat = target_tensors
        
        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = self.model(x=source_mag_ir, mat=target_mat, rgb=rgb, semantic=category)
        loss = self.criterion(outputs, target_mag_ir)
        loss.backward()
        self.optimizer.step()
    print(prof.key_averages().table(sort_by="self_cpu_memory_usage", row_limit=10), flush=True)
    return loss.item()

And this is the profiler result:
Batch 0
-------------------------------------------------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  
                                                   Name    Self CPU %      Self CPU   CPU total %     CPU total  CPU time avg       CPU Mem  Self CPU Mem      CUDA Mem  Self CUDA Mem    # of Calls  
 
                                            aten::empty         0.06%       2.653ms         0.35%      14.172ms      29.281us         492 b         492 b      41.05 Gb      41.05 Gb           484  
                               Optimizer.step-Adam.step         0.24%       9.799ms         4.26%     174.531ms     174.531ms         576 b          84 b     112.40 Mb     -55.50 Mb             1  
                                               aten::to         0.01%     495.000us        20.94%     856.849ms       4.632ms           0 b           0 b       4.66 Gb           0 b           185  
                                         aten::_to_copy         0.00%     194.000us        20.92%     856.354ms     142.726ms           0 b           0 b       4.66 Gb           0 b             6  
                                    aten::empty_strided         0.09%       3.571ms         0.34%      13.891ms      31.007us           0 b           0 b      12.42 Gb      12.42 Gb           448  
                                  cudaStreamIsCapturing         0.01%     209.000us         0.01%     209.000us       0.774us           0 b           0 b           0 b           0 b           270  
                                             cudaMalloc         1.42%      57.937ms         1.42%      57.937ms     609.863us           0 b           0 b           0 b           0 b            95  
                                            aten::copy_         0.05%       1.884ms        21.50%     879.994ms      55.000ms           0 b           0 b           0 b           0 b            16  
                                        cudaMemcpyAsync        20.79%     850.848ms        20.79%     850.848ms      85.085ms           0 b           0 b           0 b           0 b            10  
                                  cudaStreamSynchronize         0.00%     166.000us         0.00%     166.000us      27.667us           0 b           0 b           0 b           0 b             6  
-------------------------------------------------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  
Self CPU time total: 4.093s

Batch 1
-------------------------------------------------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  
                                                   Name    Self CPU %      Self CPU   CPU total %     CPU total  CPU time avg       CPU Mem  Self CPU Mem      CUDA Mem  Self CUDA Mem    # of Calls  
  
                                            aten::empty         0.20%       1.699ms         0.20%       1.699ms       4.997us           4 b           4 b      41.05 Gb      41.05 Gb           340  
                                               aten::to         0.19%       1.606ms        95.91%     810.552ms      19.770ms           0 b           0 b       4.66 Gb           0 b            41  
                                         aten::_to_copy         0.02%     171.000us        95.72%     808.946ms     134.824ms           0 b           0 b       4.66 Gb           0 b             6  
                                    aten::empty_strided         0.08%     717.000us         0.08%     717.000us       4.481us           0 b           0 b      12.31 Gb      12.31 Gb           160  
                                            aten::copy_         0.04%     340.000us        95.72%     808.879ms      50.555ms           0 b           0 b           0 b           0 b            16  
                                        cudaMemcpyAsync        95.65%     808.291ms        95.65%     808.291ms      80.829ms           0 b           0 b           0 b           0 b            10  
                                  cudaStreamSynchronize         0.02%     189.000us         0.02%     189.000us      31.500us           0 b           0 b           0 b           0 b             6  
                     Optimizer.zero_grad-Adam.zero_grad         0.04%     374.000us         0.04%     374.000us     374.000us           0 b           0 b     -57.71 Mb     -57.71 Mb             1  
                                   DataParallel.forward         0.40%       3.362ms         1.41%      11.913ms      11.913ms           0 b           0 b      54.76 Gb      -6.63 Gb             1  
                                                Scatter         0.01%      63.000us         0.02%     169.000us      84.500us           0 b           0 b           0 b           0 b             2  
-------------------------------------------------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  
Self CPU time total: 845.088ms

